# powercli access VMs without connecting to a vCenter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, virtual-machine, powercli

I need to write a PowerCLI script that gets an argument with a name of a virtual machine, and returns the VM's host name. The catch is, I shouldn't connect to the VC.

thanks for all your help (:

P.S: do any of you guys know how to connect the PowerCLI to the active directory? That'll help me in other scripts I need to make.

Thank you! (:

Comment: As I understand it, the authentication happens through vCenter - therefore you won't be able to gather information about a VM through powercli without first connecting to a vCenter server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

You would either need to authenticate with vCenter or with the ESXi host.

It is not possible to pull VM information without authentication as this would be quite a large security risk.